# SQLite3 .stats on documentation

Tags: sqlite

With SQLite3, is there any documentation about the values found after a `select` when you activate the `.stats on` option ?

What does those fields means ?

output example :

```
Memory Used:                         114280 (max 127512) bytes
Number of Outstanding Allocations:   327 (max 385)
Number of Pcache Overflow Bytes:     4104 (max 4104) bytes
Largest Allocation:                  87200 bytes
Largest Pcache Allocation:           4104 bytes
Lookaside Slots Used:                0 (max 0)
Successful lookaside attempts:       0
Lookaside failures due to size:      0
Lookaside failures due to OOM:       0
Pager Heap Usage:                    13696 bytes
Page cache hits:                     16
Page cache misses:                   2
Page cache writes:                   0
Page cache spills:                   0
Schema Heap Usage:                   1304 bytes
Statement Heap/Lookaside Usage:      3208 bytes
Fullscan Steps:                      13
Sort Operations:                     0
Autoindex Inserts:                   0
Virtual Machine Steps:               90
Reprepare operations:                0
Number of times run:                 1
Memory used by prepared stmt:        3208
Bytes received by read():            34223
Bytes sent to write():               1998
Read() system calls:                 76
Write() system calls:                104
Bytes read from storage:             1650688
Bytes written to storage:            0
Cancelled write bytes:               0
```

Comment: Everything but lookaside is obvious, and that's described at https://sqlite.org/malloc.html#_lookaside_memory_allocator